# How to get the character to the left of cursor in Visual Studio Extension?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, api, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to get the character on the left of cursor. I've got the handler that intercepts the `LineChanged` event.

```
OnLineChanged(TextPoint startPoint, TextPoint endPoint, int Hint)
```

I couldn't find any built in method to get that from `TextPoint`s.

What's the best way to do that?

Also, is there a way to check if the active window has IntelliSense window open? I want to abort the event handler execution if IntelliSense is open.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi, "accepted answer"?, It seems that Sergey's answer helps resolve your issue so you accept it. You can consider marking it as answer if it do work. Just a reminded:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the character to the left of the EnvDTE.TextPoint:

```
string CharacterToTheLeft(EnvDTE.TextPoint p)
{
    EnvDTE.EditPoint editPoint = p.CreateEditPoint();
    editPoint.CharLeft();
    return editPoint.GetText(1);
}
```

To create an edit point at the current cursor position from EnvDTE.TextPoint startPoint:

```
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = startPoint.Parent.Selection;
    EnvDTE.EditPoint editPoint = ts.ActivePoint.CreateEditPoint();
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's a way to check if the active editor window has IntelliSense popup open?

Comment: @nick-s Please open a separate question for it.

Comment: Here it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000759/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-active-window-has-intellisense-window-open