# Is there a way to check if the active window has IntelliSense popup open?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, api, visual-studio-extensions

Is there a way to check if the currently active window has IntelliSense popup open in a Visual Studio Extension?

I want to abort the TextChanged event handler execution if IntelliSense is open.

Comment: Any update for this issue? If the Sergey's answer is helpful for you, please consider marking it as answer, it will be beneficial to other community members which has the similar issue. Just a reminder:)

Comment: I haven't been able to test. Of course, I'll accept when I've tested if it works. @LanceLi-MSFT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.ICompletionBroker.[IsCompletionActive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.icompletionbroker.iscompletionactive?view=visualstudiosdk-2019)(textView);